# I'd like to add a like button to this flutter blog app

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-layout

This project can be found here:https://github.com/Santos-Enoque/flutter_blog_app

So far I have this connected to firebase realtime database and it works well. I'm trying to add a like button to the Home page(lib/screens/home.dart) where all the posts are listed.

The Homepage displays the blog results using a Card with a ListTile. The trailing property of the ListTile card is already used so I'd like to use the leading property of the ListTile card to display a favourite icon which would increment a counter++ when tapped and also save the results to Firebase. Just like Facebook's like button.
Here's the code below:

```
                          child: Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: ListTile(
                                onTap: (){
                                  _incrementCounter();                                
                                },

                                leading: FittedBox(
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Icon(Icons.favorite),
                                      Text(postsList[index].counter.toString()
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  ),

                                title: Text(
                                  postsList[index].title,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                trailing: Text(
                                  timeago.format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(postsList[index].date)),
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.grey),
                                ),

                              ),
                              subtitle: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 14.0),
                                child: Text(postsList[index].body, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

Here's the _increment counter code:

```
    try {
      var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('posts/{postId}/counter');
      await ref.once().then((data) async => {
        await ref.set(data.value + 1),

      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
```

![Home page of blog]https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMK6C-Wx2vZHHbE2jDMQsfYNnwl9OWK_5W8OKOfiIChcXt-gnWnCH7ba_EpyRnRAA?key=cGxkRkVSSk9PQTdtTXB0MzZBRDNHNUVzSGxlcDVB

The blog posts are displayed as cards as in the image ... I'm trying to add an icon on the left side of the card(leading) plus an incrementing value everytime someone taps the icon. Something like the like button on facebook. And also save the data to firebase realtime database.

Any help is much appreciated ... Thank you all!

Comment: Provide your  specific requirement . need clarity.........

Comment: @Kit Mateyawa as your question is on UI, please add a snapshot or mock picture of where you are at, and what you would like it to be instead. Also, state clearly what you want to do next, and where is your blocker. About the code, post only the part of the code which is relevant to this issue, so that we can actually help you

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you may want to do is add this function to your onPressed. You will also need to set the text of the next to the icon equal to the new value read.

```
void like() async {
    try {
      var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('path to likes for a post');
      await ref.once().then((data) async => {
        await ref.set(data.value + 1);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

P.S.- You may find this video of use: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8_7RTRRmHo

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I managed to fix the UI issue but I couldn't get it to work. Please take a look. My full code is here: [link]https://github.com/kitmt/cmfiflutterapp/blob/master/lib/prayer/screens/prayer.dart Thank you!

Comment: On print all posts show up: `I/flutter (31567): {date: 1583412633724, counter: 5, body: yes maybe you can see, title: kindly}
I/flutter (31567): {date: 1583499007444, counter: 12, body: Thanks, title: Kind}
I/flutter (31567): {date: 1583499929773, counter: 0, body: yes maybe you should know, title: thanks}
I/flutter (31567): {date: 1583501476104, counter: 0, body: I'm blessed, title: what are you}
I/flutter (31567): {date: 1583503757100, counter: 0, body: hd DTH jii, title: h HCG hh}` but counter is not connecting tofirebase ... plus values don't increment when I tap card

Comment: https://github.com/kitmt/cmfiflutterapp/blob/master/lib/prayer/models/post.dart

Comment: https://github.com/kitmt/cmfiflutterapp/blob/master/lib/prayer/db/PostService.dart

Comment: Aha, the reference (ref in the code above) needs to be set to `var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('posts/{postId}/counter');` Where {postId} is the key of the of the key value pair whose value is the Post object the user has tapped.

Comment: I adjusted with your code and still no joy. I think somthing wrong with my code here:`Text("$counter"),` is not updating in UI

Comment: managed to get data using`postsList[index].counter.toString(),`  but still can't update counter data with onTap

Comment: Not sure why Github is not updating but I just changed `Text('$counter') to Text(postsList[index].counter.toString())` to get data from firebase.

Comment: Sorry for being vague ... the edited code was on line 86 of: https://github.com/kitmt/cmfiflutterapp/blob/master/lib/prayer/screens/prayer.dart

Comment: It was me who was vague, sorry. In `var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('posts/{postId}/counter');`, `{postid}` needs to be replaced by `index` or whatever the Post object is stored under in your database. Since this needs to be constant for each post, I would primitively recommend using 0, 1, 2 ... to number the posts in the database just so you can get something working on the screen right now, but I don't know the other implications of this.

Comment: Also, it would be best to keep it as Text(counter.toString()) unless you know for sure that PostsList will update when the database is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped with this:

Code for UI:

```
leading: FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
           child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.favorite),
            Text(postsList[index].counter.toString()
                  ),
                 ],
                ),
            ),
```

Code for Function:

```
onTap: (){
     _incrementCounter(postsList[index].key);
}
...

void _incrementCounter(key) async {
    try {
      var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('posts/'+ key +'/counter');
      await ref.once().then((data) async => {
        await ref.set(data.value + 1),
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```