# How can I get the auto generated key from Firebase in my Flutter project?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

This is a continuation from this post: [I'd like to add a like button to this flutter blog app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60538031/id-like-to-add-a-like-button-to-this-flutter-blog-app)

Currently I can print out the auto generated keys in Firebase realtime database using `print(snap.key);`

My problem is adding it to this onTap function _incrementCounter. Not sure what to do here. Of course if I replaced`+ snap.key +` with any of the firebase posts key then the function will work for that paticular post only:

```
void _incrementCounter() async {
    try {
      var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('posts/'+ snap.key +'/counter');
      await ref.once().then((data) async => {
        await ref.set(data.value + 1),
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the key to your function. Or am I misunderstanding something?

```
...
onTap: (){
     _incrementCounter(postsList[index].key);
}
...

void _incrementCounter(key) async {
    try {
      var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('posts/'+ key +'/counter');
      await ref.once().then((data) async => {
        await ref.set(data.value + 1),
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```